# Is it standard to add a 0 and a 1 to the input layer of a neural network?

Tags: neural-networks

Is it standard to add a 0 and a 1 to the input layer of a neural network?

I haven't seen it done, but my experience of the breadth of neural networks is low. It would seem like not doing this would hinder logical calculations until the second layer – or deeper – when the network was able to reliably generate this input.

Comment: Please give an example of what you mean.

Comment: it's not standard, it's actually useless. but may you explain what you mean by the network *generating* the input? are you talking about autoencoders? why did you use the tag "conv-neural-networks" even if your question has apparently nothing to do with those?

Comment: because sometimes direction is hard to find.